# Android Facebook Response parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing, facebook-graph-api

`{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"98374978103","birthday":"04\/19\/1991","gender":"male","email":"email@gmail.com","name":"Wasfasf"}, error: null}`
I am getting facebook response as above string
How to parse this string.
I am doing it this way

```
 try {
                                String res = response.toString();
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                                JSONArray arr = obj.optJSONArray("graphObject");
                                for(int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String id = jsonObject.optString("id").toString();
                                    String bday = jsonObject.optString("birthday").toString();
                                    String gender = jsonObject.optString("gender").toString();
                                    String email = jsonObject.optString("email").toString();
                                    String name = jsonObject.optString("name").toString();


                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

It throws the exception :

```
Unterminated object at character 25 of {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"983797084978103","birthday":"04\/19\/1991","gender":"male","email":"waleedbinilyas@gmail.com","name":"Waleed Bin Ilyas"}, error: null}
```

Comment: This is json response, it shows this it is invalid json. Please give me correct one

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Still Json is not proper, anyways try above posts which are possible duplicates of your question. If you will not find any solution then post your question with some code what you have tried

Comment: You can visit this site 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: @sam_k it is the response i am getting from faceboook graph api ..

Comment: Whats problem in your code. Please tell us your problem What you want to do with json response

Answer (score 1):

I have done in this way and works fine perfectly

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //before set conteview
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
      //  AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

         LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest graphRequest=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                        Log.d("Graph Response",graphResponse.toString());

                        String myCustomizedResponse = graphResponse.getJSONObject().toString();

                        Log.d("Ketan_Ramani",graphResponse.getJSONObject().toString());

                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myCustomizedResponse);

                            String id = obj.getString("id");
                            String first_name = obj.getString("first_name");
                            String last_name = obj.getString("last_name");
                            String email = obj.getString("email");


                            Log.d("Id",id);
                            Log.d("FirstName",first_name);
                            Log.d("LastName",last_name);
                            Log.d("Email",email);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Utils.hide_dialog();

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,email");
                graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
                graphRequest.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please also explain in a few words what you changed/did?

Comment: i have just retrieved graphResponse object and stored that object into myCustomizedResponse and from that object i have retrieved id,first_name,last_name,email.

Comment: **String myCustomizedResponse = graphResponse.getJSONObject().toString();** This is an important line

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but it would be better to put that into your answer and not below it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get a object like graphObject do this:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject([jsonString]);
ArrayList<SomeClass> listObj = jObj.getJSONArray("graphObject");

if (listObj.length() != 0){
     for (int i = 0; i < listObj.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject c = listObj.getJSONObject(i);
          c.getString("name");
          c.getString("gender");
           .
           .
           .
     }
}
```

Edit: SomeClass = Same Fields that you have in your json´s fields, in this case: id,birthday,gender,email,name.

Comment: but how can we give JSONArray in ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you.

```
try {
    String res = response.toString();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("graphObject");
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = jsonObject.getString("id").toString();
        String bday = jsonObject.getString("birthday").toString();
        String gender = jsonObject.getString("gender").toString();
        String email = jsonObject.getString("email").toString();
        String name = jsonObject.getString("name").toString();


    }
}    
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note : I have not tested this code.

Answer (score 0):

The given json is invalid,you can use [jsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validte your json Feed
assuming feed below the correct feed

`{
    "Response": {
        "responseCode": 200,
        "graphObject": {
            "id": "983797088103",
            "birthday": "04/19/1991",
            "gender": "male",
            "email": "email@wamil",
            "name": "name"
        },
        " error": null
    }
}`

If you are using an IDE like intellij/Android studio use the plugin like [Dtonator](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7834?pr=idea) to generate the Gson DTO's,which will look like this

```
public class FaceBookResponse {

@SerializedName("Response")
public Response Response;

public static class GraphObject {
    @SerializedName("birthday")
    public String birthday;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    public String gender;
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("email")
    public String email;
}

public static class Response {
    @SerializedName("error")
    public String error;
    @SerializedName("graphObject")
    public GraphObject graphObject;
    @SerializedName("responseCode")
    public int responseCode;
}
}
```

Now you can simply parse your feed using the below two lines.

```
private final Gson gson = new Gson();
FaceBookResponse response=mGson.fromJson(json, mClazz);
```

Comment: what kind of object is that ? mClazz

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way

```
 try {


                                String id = object.getString("id");

                                String uname = object.getString("name");

                                String emailid = object.getString("email");

                                String gender = object.getString("gender");

                                String bday = object.getString("birthday");


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Graph object is an object not array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCompleted(JSONObject facebookResponseObject, GraphResponse response) {
                                // Application code
                               // Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                Log.v("facebook_response", facebookResponseObject.toString());
}}
```

You are converting response object of type GraphResponse and then doing operations on it.

Instead do this:facebookResponseObject.toString() and then you can easily do this --> Log.e("facebook_response_id",id);